# Как из колонки с датой получить только номер месяца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Имею фрейм данных:

```
d = {'name': ['carl', 'tot', 'brick', 'rick', None], 'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Нужно в значениях колонки `Date` оставить только номер месяца.

Пока дошёл только до такого:

```
d.Date = d.Date.str.split('/\d*')
```

Но этот код создаёт ещё и ненужные мне пустые значения.

Comment: номер месяца это первые два символа, просто сделай срез

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Вариант 1:

```
df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.month
```

результат (месяц - целое число):

```
In [187]: df
Out[187]:
    name        Date Address  month
0   carl  11/05/2011      AR     11
1    tot  09/02/2010      YU      9
2  brick  11/01/2014      RU     11
3   rick  11/20/2020      EU     11
4   None  09/30/2009      BY      9
```

---

#### Вариант 2:

```
df["month"] = df["Date"].str[:2]
```

результат (месяц - строка):

```
In [190]: df
Out[190]:
    name        Date Address month
0   carl  11/05/2011      AR    11
1    tot  09/02/2010      YU    09
2  brick  11/01/2014      RU    11
3   rick  11/20/2020      EU    11
4   None  09/30/2009      BY    09
```

---

#### Вариант 3:

```
d = {'name': ['carl', 'tot', 'brick', 'rick', None], 'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'], 'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df["month"] = df["Date"].str.extract("^(\d+)")
```

результат (месяц - строка):

```
In [208]: df
Out[208]:
    name        Date Address month
0   carl  11/05/2011      AR    11
1    tot   9/02/2010      YU     9
2  brick   1/01/2014      RU     1
3   rick  12/20/2020      EU    12
4   None   9/30/2009      BY     9
```

---

#### Вариант 4:

```
df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%m")
```

результат (месяц - строка):

```
In [210]: df
Out[210]:
    name        Date Address month
0   carl  11/05/2011      AR    11
1    tot   9/02/2010      YU    09
2  brick   1/01/2014      RU    01
3   rick  12/20/2020      EU    12
4   None   9/30/2009      BY    09
```

---

PS варианты 1 и 4 (с использованием `pd.to_datetime(...)`) - самые надежные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Маленькая поправочка: 

df["month"] = df["Date"].str[:1]

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off, `df["Date"].str[:1]` - вернет только первый символ строки - вам нужна только первая цифра месяца?? Вы об этом в вопросе не упомянули

Comment: Не первый, а первые 2. Счет с 0. Спасибо поставил ;)

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off, а вы попробуйте ваш вариант! ;)

Comment: Согласен, но, если

d = {'name': ['carl', 'tot', 'brick', 'rick', None],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

То по другому надо

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off, добавил еще несколько вариантов решения

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off Правая граница у срезов не включительная, так что `[:1]` возвращает один только нулевой элемент.

Comment: Согласен, был не прав)